# DOM EventHandler on AJAX not firing

Tags: javascript, ajax

Simple DIV Container

```
<div id="ajaxcontainer">AJAX LOADED HERE</div>
```

This is the AJAX called back

```
<script>document.getElementById('ajaxcontent').addEventListener('onmouseover', PagesMenu.init, false)</script>
<div id="ajaxcontent">Menu Content to be Acted On</div>
```

This is then parsed so that the JScript can run.

It parses fine.  The script is recognised in my ajax parser.  It should attach the event listener to the ajaxcontent div that is loaded along with the script via ajax. But it doesnt run.

Any ideas.

Ive tried a number of different Handler types, onload, onmouseover, onfocus, onclick, none of them work on the div container that is supposed to run the function from the event handler which isnt appended to the div.

Im using pure Javascript, no Jquery or other.  Just want flat Javascript answers.

Comment: This is not very clear at all, is that script tag inside content that is loaded with javascript? If so, place a `console.log` in it, and see if it's executed at all, then search for something like *"javascript in ajax not executed"* on this site

Comment: i have a console log on the parse of the script, it parse fine no problems.  The parse is done in the AJAX call.  This parser runs scripts fine.

The script and div are the ajax content. ajax call brings back the div ajaxcontent and i can see the script in the source.  It doesnt seem to run at all.

If i change the container on the addEventListener from ajaxcontent, to ajaxcontainer.  My thought being that the ajaxcontent div was not visible yet, it still doesnt run.

Comment: Well, if it's in the posted order, the script runs before the element is available in the DOM, so you should probably swap places, adding the script tag ***after*** the element in the DOM.

Comment: Tried this as well

<div id="ajaxcontent">Menu Content to be Acted On</div>
<script>document.getElementById('ajaxcontent').addEventListener('onmouseover', PagesMenu.init, false)</script>

Comment: It's also just `addEventListener('mouseover' ...` without the *"on"* part

Comment: document.getElementById('ajaxcontent').addEventListener('MouseOver', PagesMenu.init, false)

still no worky

Comment: Why the heck would you add uppercase characters ?

Comment: tried upper, lower, tried click event, host of others.  Its like the addEventListener call is not being triggered at all.

Comment: if i were to put in, alert("test parse"), it pops up an alert.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahbd4hvL/

Comment: And open the console(F12) and check for errors on your site

Comment: ok, dont know what i did, but i have it working on a click event.  <script>document.getElementById('ajaxcontent').addEventListener('click', PagesMenu.init, false)</script>

Comment: what event can be used to make it run as soon as the div is loaded by the ajax. i have this working on a flat page using window.load and window.unload, but due to ajax, and div, these two arent available.

cheers for your help. got it working, but not user freindly yet

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot to put `""` `<div id="ajaxcontainer">`